# Поиск пути в лабиринте с использованием динамического программирования

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, динамическое-программирование

Для какой цели нужно использовать динамические структуры, например **списки, стеки** для поиска пути/обхода лабиринта?

Если такой алгоритм вполне рабочий, с использованием только рекурсии

То есть просто проверяем по вертикали и горизонтали есть ли пути, если есть то идем, и помечаем пути где мы уже были.

```
procedure f(y, x: byte);
begin
 if arr[y, x] = 5 then
 else
     arr[y, x] := 2;

 if arr[y, x - 1] = 0 then
    f(y, x - 1);
 if arr[y, x + 1] = 0 then
    f(y, x + 1);
 if arr[y + 1, x] = 0 then
    f(y + 1, x);
 if arr[y - 1, x] = 0 then
    f(y - 1, x);
end;
```

Comment: ДП в лабиринте не поможет. Нужен обычный обход в ширину (это в глубину написано). И да, обход в ширину - это очередь.

Comment: Динамическое программирование и динамические структуры - это вещи не взаимосвязанные. общего, грубо говоря, не имеющие. А для лабиринтов лучше, пожалуй, подходят алгоритмы на графах. А вот тут и используются - например, при поиске в ширину - очередь, в глубину - стек...

Comment: Так а зачем использовать стек? Если все с помощью рекурсии решается

Comment: Я так полагаю, чтобы записать путь. Т.к обход его только находит, но не записывает

Comment: "Для какой цели нужно использовать... списки, стеки для поиска пути" — а почему вы вообще решили, что вам их **нужно** использовать для поиска пути? У вас учебное задание "реализовать поиск пути с использованием списков и стеков"?

Comment: В задание сказано: "Выполнить с использованием любой структуры данных".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот например BFS (поиск в ширину) использует очередь и при этом находит кратчайший путь. Ваш же вариант будет искать какой-то случайный путь. Можно привести аналогию и с другими алгоритмами. У каждого из них есть свои особенности и они применимы в разных случаях, так что использование стеков и списков делается не просто так.